# Blending In Metal with Same Alpha

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am drawing three squares as in the Picture[image]

I am adding color of red with alpha 0.2.

In the overlapping areas also I want the areas to be in the alpha of 0.2. Now It is coming as 0.6. How can I do that suggest. Currently my pipeline Descriptor is

```
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

Do I need to do it in Pipeline Descriptor or In Shader ?

Comment: You need to be clearer about exactly what you want to happen, what you're getting, and how they differ. I thought your question was clear, but the discussion in comments to Abix's answer gives me doubts. Try posting a screenshot of what you're getting and, if possible, an image of what you want (a mock-up or the results from OpenGL if you have that).

Comment: @KenThomases Need is when a finger touches the screen I am drawing three rectangles using the Touch Point. They are overlapping Rectangles as above in Picture. I need to draw them with alpha 0.2 In overlapping Places currently alpha is 0.4. In second touch It can add If the First touch and Second Touch Overlap. If not alpha should be 0.2.

Comment: @KenThomases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741792/mtlrenderpipelinedescriptor-blending

Answer (score 1):

If you want the final result to have the same alpha as which you are drawing, you need to set them as:

```
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
 pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .zero
```

Which will mean that the final alpha will have no contribution from the target on which you are rendering.

Comment: It is not working. For your reference I added the code.  https://github.com/PIRANAVARUBAN/Blend

Comment: From your code, it appears to me that you are trying to draw the rectangles repeatedly on the target with an uniform transparency. For each touch, seems like you want the color of the rectangles to have the same value. But currently it is becoming more and more red with each draw. Is that correct?

Comment: In a single touch from that point I am drawing three rectangles. If those three rectangles in same Alpha ok for me. If the next touch overlap If it adds It is ok.

Comment: Well in that case the blending of alpha is not relevant. The destination alpha would not matter. One way to achieve this could be to compose the triangle primitives per touch in such a way that they do not overlap. That way for single touch, the color would not get added. But for a overlapping touch, it would. But this will need a lot of code changes for you (to position non-overlapping triangles to compose the same shape).

Comment: Cannot we do anything in the shader so that overlapping areas getting the constant alpha ?

Comment: If you are okay with all the rectangles (not only those three per touch) having the same shade of red, then you can keep a copy of the canvas (target texture, which is pure white in this example) and pass it into the fragment shader. In fragment shader mix the pixels picked from this canvas with the red color with an weight of 0.2. Disable the blend all together in the pipeline descriptor. But the colors will then never add. If that is okay.

Comment: How to do that can you please Ellaborate ?

Comment: For example if your canvas is an image, create a Metal texture from the image. Now in your fragment shader, take this texture as an input. In the same fragment shader, now get the pixel of the texture (float4 canvasColor = canvasTexture.sample(defaultSampler,  params.textureCoordinates)). Then mix this color with your drawing color (float4 finalColor = mix(canvasColor, brushColor, 0.2);) and then return this value from your fragment shader. Disable blending the render pipeline descriptor. This should draw all the rectangles with an uniform transparency of 0.2.